# Failed click using Selenium and XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, click, robotframework

For test automation on a web app I am currently using Robot framework and the Selenium library. There comes the moment I want to click on a button and then I wait for an element to appear. Alas, the click, although recorded successful in the log, does not lead to the apparition of the element I wish. In fact it is as if the click never happened.

To click on the button, I retrieve it using xpath. Using Firepath I successfully verified that the element is unique and does exist but what it shows leads me to think I have found why the button is not clicked correctly

[image: xpath]

You can see in light blue the button I want to click on and wrapped with dotted line the zone detected by firepath.

Is it possible that the click is done next to the button instead on it ?

Here is the incriminated line :

```
Click Element     xpath=(.//button[contains(@id,'editContract')])[1
```

Edit :
HTML of the page :

```
<button id="listContractTableForm:listContractTable:0:editContract" name="listContractTableForm:listContractTable:0:editContract" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" onclick="window.location.href='destinationPage?faces-redirect=true&amp;contractEntityContractId=678'">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-search"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
</button>
```

Comment: here is the html code of the button, I am sorry I am not allowed to show much of the code.

Comment: Best guess is your xpath matches another element in the DOM, and it's clicking that instead.  Try your xpath with a `Get Matching Xpath Count` and see how many results it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `span` with class containing `ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-search`

```
//button[contains(@id,'listContractTableForm')]/span[contains(@class,'ui-icon-search')]
```

if you want the `span` with `class="ui-button-text ui-c"` simply change the `class` in the xpath